# possible efficient ways of transferring files from one server to another

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, batch-file, file-transfer

what are the possible good and efficient ways of transferring files from one server to another? In this case it will be from windows server 2003 to windows server 2008 r2. I am thinking Powershell cmdlets  or batch files could be a help here but not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i suggest you use robocopy since it has really nice features such as auto retry when the diskspace is full or when there is a network outage.
in your case assuming you have network connection between those 2 machines.
robocopy "source" "destination" /(any switch you might add)

robocopy \22.22.222.222\c$\2003\folder \11.11.111.111\c$\2008\folder /E /Z
you can check /? for more options it has quite a few.

hope you find this useful good luck.

Comment: +1 RoboCopy also has a GUI that can make it a bit easier for some users

Comment: thanks. I am not aware of its function yet but looks like what I want. so, how can I put the remote server credentials? username and password?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your edit you would have to "map" the C:\ drive of the second machine as a disk on the first machine (for example, as F:) and then use:

> xcopy c:\2003\folder d:\2008\folder /s

---

If it is just files you want to move you could use a batch file and "[xcopy](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm)".

> xcopy X:\ Y:\ /s

This will copy evrything from X:\ to Y:\ and subdirectories.

You'll "map" the C: drive of the se use xcopy C:\2003\folder C:\200

You could also look at [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php), USB sticks, FTP transfer, burn to disk, move to external HD...

Comment: ok but how would that xcopy code transfer the files from one to another. let's be more specific here; I wanna transfer files from -**c:\2003\folder** on server whose ip is **11.11.111.111** to c:\2008\folder on server whose ip is **22.22.222.222**

Comment: If you're running this command from a machine other than the two mentioned (you'll need admin access to access the c$ share): xcopy \\11.11.111.111\c$\2003\folder\ \\22.22.222.222\c$\2008\folder\ [any cool options you want]

Answer (score 1):

My current favorite file transfer tools is [richcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog) mainly becasue it's multithreaded and can fill whatever size pipe you have between servers (presuming you have the disk IO available).. Richopy is a replacement for robocopy.

Comment: robocopy on Win7 and Win2k8 is multithreaded as well.

Comment: @mfinni it *can* be multithreaded, under win 7 but by default it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of link you have between the servers, I would like to throw in a recommendation for [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php). It has proven itself as very fast and reliable, even over unstable links.

http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php